# In C++, how can I test if an object is an instance of a Child class in the Parent class' constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assert that a pointer passed into a Parent class' constructor is only `NULL` if the object is of a *specific* Child class type using `dynamic_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(void *ptr);
    virtual ~Parent(); // to make Parent polymorphic
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    Child1() : Parent(0) { std::cout << "Child1 ctor\n";};
};
class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    Child2() : Parent(0) { std::cout << "Child2 ctor\n";};
};

Parent::Parent(void *ptr) {
    if (0 == ptr && 0 == dynamic_cast<Child1*>(this)) {
         std::cerr<<"ERROR\n";
    }
}
Parent::~Parent() {};

int main(void) {
    Child1 *c1 = new Child1();
    Child2 *c2 = new Child2();
}
```

This prints:

```
ERROR
Child1 ctor
ERROR
Child2 ctor
```

Whereas, I expect to see `ERROR` during the `Child2` construction *only*.

Why is `dynamic_cast` returning non-NULL when I'm in `Parent` constructor for `Child1` called from `Child1`'s constructor initialization list?  Also, is there a different way to accomplish this test?

Comment: I have a feeling that such a design would violate the "is-a" relationship of inheritance...

Comment: 1) Why would you want to do this? 2) The reason you can't do this is because the child isn't constructed yet.

Comment: Because in reality, I have 10 different child classes that must have non-NULL pointers, but only 1 child class that will have the NULL pointer.  I'm trying to avoid putting this check in 10 different classes.

Comment: @Ross: Why don't you just use a static helper function in `Parent` for this?  `private: static void checkPointer(void *ptr, bool b) { if (ptr == NULL && !b) std::cerr << "ERROR\n"; } }`.

Comment: That still violates D.R.Y. ( and I know I'm violating KISS :-) ), but you gave me a different idea.  I can implement the _exact_ same check that I wrote in the accessor method and the `dynamic_cast` will work.  My reason for wanting to do this crap is that I have control over `Parent` and `Child1`, but I wont have control over all the other `Child2` ... `ChildN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess the issue is that dynamic_cast works off the vtable, which isn't set up until after the constructor finishes. Thus, you can't call dynamic_cast in the constructor.

I can't think of any immediate ways to detect this in the constructor without using templates and making everything static. Why do you want this behaviour? It seems quite dubious - Parent really should have no knowledge of the derivatives Child1 and Child2.

If you want to protect against a null pointer in when Child2 calls the parent constructor, why not just protect against it in Child2's constructor and throw an exception if it is null?

Comment: There are many Child2's.  I was trying to avoid putting the check in a whole bunch of classes.

Comment: Why not make a CheckedParent class, and derive the Child2s from that?

Answer (score 2):

When you are in Parent constructor -which is a base class- the Child has not been constructed yet. As a result, within the constructor of Parent the dynamic type of this will always be Parent.

Comment: So RTTI information is iteratively built by each level of constructors?

Comment: No, RTTI information is static and built at compile time. Within constructors and destructors, derived classes have not been built yet or have already been destroyed. You may say however that the dynamic type of the object is iteratively built by each level of constructors.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do thins like that would be to create proected constructor in base class, and pass parameter indicating how to initalize it - this way child classes would decide how they want it, and base class would just arrange things as requested.